# JavaScript to search for unique objects and pull sum from values

Tags: javascript

I'm very familiar with PowerShell but now I'm trying to tackle learning JavaScript.

So in PowerShell, I have a variable that I'm doing a `Where-Object -eq value` and doing a measure to get the total sum of all the values with that object name

```
(($MarketPlaceCharges | Where-Object {$_.orderNumber -eq "cf322da4-ddba-48e0-84a7-61cc7663d012"})).extendedcost | Measure-Object -Sum
```

Within JavaScript I have an each which is presenting me with all the objects, not the ones that are unique only to that orderNumber

```
_.each(azure_resources, function(ar){
    result.push({
      subscriptionGuid: ar["subscriptionGuid"],
      subscriptionName: ar["subscriptionName"],
      usageStartDate: ar["usageStartDate"],
      usageEndDate: ar["usageEndDate"]
      costCenter: ar["costCenter"],
      accountName: ar["accountName"],
      departmentName: ar["departmentName"],
      publisherName: ar["publisherName"]
      planName: ar["planName"]
      instanceId: ar["instanceId"]
      consumedQuantity: ar["consumedQuantity"]
      resourceRate: ar["resourceRate"]
      extendedCost: ar["extendedCost"]
    })
})
```

How would I go about creating a filter that finds all unique order numbers then does a filter for everyone regardless of how many of the same order and sum up the extendedcost?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter native function:

```
array.filter(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```

documentaion:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp

Answer (score 0):

The [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of `Array` returns a new `Array` keeping only items that meet a given criteria, and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) takes an array and combines the items into a single value (which covers summing). You don't need libraries like `lodash` or `underscore` for this sort of calculation.

```
const sum = azure_resources
  .filter(resource => resource.orderNumber === 'cf322da4-ddba-48e0-84a7-61cc7663d012')
  .reduce((total, resource) => total + resource.extendedCost, 0);
```